# Why are os.system and subprocess.call spawning so many processes?

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system, scite

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import re

## fname_ext=sys.argv[1]
fname_ext=r"C:\mine\.cs\test.cs"
exe=os.path.splitext(fname_ext)[0]+".exe" # Executable
fdir=os.path.split(fname_ext)[0]
fcontent=open(fname_ext).read()

p_using=re.compile("\s*using\s+((\w+[.]*)+)")
p_namespace=re.compile("\s*namespace\s+(\w+)")
usings=p_using.findall(fcontent)
usings=[x[0] for x in usings]
references=[]
for i in os.listdir(fdir):
    path=fdir+"\\"+i
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(path) or (not path.endswith('cs')):continue
        with open(path) as fp:
            content=fp.read()
            namespaces=p_namespace.findall(content)
            for n in namespaces:
                if n in usings and 'System' not in n:
                    references+=[path]
    except:
        pass

command="csc /nologo "+" ".join(references)+" "+fname_ext
## command=" ".join(references)
#~ ---------------------------------------------------------
# Build:
option=1
if option==0:
    # using os.system
    print ">>",command
    if os.system(command)==0:
        os.system(exe)
else:
    #~ Using subprocess module
    ## print type(references)
    command=['csc']
    ## print command,references
    command.extend(["/nologo","/out:"+exe])
    command.extend(references)
    command.append(fname_ext)
    ## print command
    if subprocess.call(command,shell=True)==0:
        ## print "running %s"%exe
        subprocess.call([exe],shell=True)
    else:
        pass
        ## print "Failed to run"
#~ ---------------------------------------------------------
```

I have this code above that is supposed to run a Csharp program from `SciTE`. It searches
every `.cs` file in the directory and finds the file with the namespace that the current
file has included. The command to run the file in SciTE is:
    `command.go.*.cs=python C:\mine\.py\csc.py  $(FilePath)`
    `command.go.subsystem.*.cs=0`

That program logic part is okay.
The issue is that when hit F5 with sample Csharp code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using MyNamespace;
class Test{
    public static void Main(String[] args){
        MyObject inst=new MyObject();
        MyObject.self_destruct(inst);
    }
}
```

it runs ok. But when I uncomment the second `fname_ext` and comment the first one
and run the csc.py file, a window opens and keeps running, printing `command`(this happens
using the `os.system` option). When you use `the subprocess.call` option, the same thing 
happens but this time only when `shell=True`. It ran for only 15 seconds and there were 800+
cmd.exe and python.exe processes.I had to wait almost 5 minutes after killing `cmd.exe` 
for the mouse to start responding and 2 minutes more for desktop peek to work. 
When `shell=False`, it runs ok, the same way as when you hit the F5 key from the file.
**What is happening here?**
**What is `shell=True` doing that makes it behave that way?**

Comment: Can you log enough information to see what `sys.argv` is in each case? Because the obvious guess is that you're running your own script rather than the thing you actually want to run.

Comment: Actually, Scite is the one passing to sys.argv(the $(FilePath)). It passes the string "C:\mine\.cs\test.cs". I created the second fname_ext so that I could switch between the two when testing. It outputs the same results when I run csc.py and when I run test.cs, so I don't think I'm running my own script. Even if it were the same script, the results would be similar irregardless of of the value of the shell argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll take a stab at this. If I understand the situation, this script is called csc.py and you want to call the csc c# compiler. When you run `csc /nologo (etc...)` through cmd.exe, it starts looking for something called 'csc' with a known extension. It finds csc.py in the current directory and since .py is a registered extension, that's what gets executed.

The solution is to rename your python file or call out 'csc.exe' explicitly.

Comment: I feel really stupid. It works when I rename it to casc.py(meaningless). I was running my own script, it just wasn't that obvious. @abarnet was partially right. It'll also run if you unregister .PY extension from %PATHEXT%(it's pointless though). If you combine both answers, you get the full explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `sys.argv` looks something like this:

```
['python', r'C:\mine\.py\csc.py', 'whatever.cs']
```

So, with the `fname_ext` line uncommented, you set `fname_ext` to `r'C:\mine\.py\csc.py'`. Which means your script ends up just running itself—which again runs itself, etc., as fast as possible until your system chokes.

The reason it doesn't happen with `shell=False` is that you can't actually exec a Python script. Ultimately you end up calling [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with your script, which tries to interpret it as a .exe file, fails, and returns an error. But with `shell=True`, you pass your script to `cmd.exe` to run as a program, and *it* does the same thing an interactive prompt or Explorer would do: finds the right mapping to execute .py files and uses it. (And `os.system` does effectively the same thing as `shell=True`, but with a couple extra layers tossed in for good measure.)

Comment: I'm kinda confused. When I have a test.cs tab open, and I run it, SciTE passes the filepath to the script, i.e python C:\mine\.py\csc.py C:\mine\.cs\test.cs . Won't sys.argv[1] still be the filepath(which the script uses) and sys.argv[0] be the name of the script(csc.py). I'm seeing a third item in the list, how's that?